# How to format Read-only filesystem drive?

Tags: format, read-only, 18.10, hfs+

I can't format a USB drive, it says "read only filesystem".
I tried mkfs.vfat, wipefs -a, using gparted but nothing worked, always returns "Read-only filesystem". The problem seems to be caused by an HFS+ partition. It seems like even root is not allowed to write on the drive: I tried every terminal command with root privileges an it keeps returning "failed to open for writing: Read-only file system". I'm running Ubuntu 18.10. Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: You can analyze the problem, and if you are lucky, solve the problem according to this link (and links from it: [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)